# How does this forces singleton?

Tags: c++, templates, singleton

In some code, I saw singleton template

```
template<typename T>
class Singleton
{
public:
    Singleton(T& instance)
    {
        assert(!sfpInstance || (sfpInstance==&instance));
        sfpInstance = &instance;
    }
    static T& getInstance()
    {
        assert(sfpInstance);
        return *sfpInstance;
    }
private:
    static T*   sfpInstance;
};
```

And classes used like this:

```
class MyClass : public Singleton<MyClass>
{
   protected:
      MyClass() : Singleton<MyClass>(*this) {}
}
```

I don't know how can this be used as singleton?

If it can be used, what is the proper way to use it.

EDIT: MyClass constructor is protected.

Comment: The short answer is "don't use singletons, they're evil and impossible to debug".

Comment: The constructor in `Singleton` ought to be protected.

Comment: The proper way to use a Singleton is not at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code won't work at all since there is no publicly available constructor of MyClass and Singleton is no friend of MyClass.

Now, if the MyClass constructor /were/ public, each call of the MyClass constructor would check whether the global sfpInstance pointer already points somewhere object, and triggers the assertion if it does. Thereby, only a single instance of MyClass can be constructed during the program run. Note that this method is not really elegant since it does not track the destruction of the MyClass singleton instance.

Comment: the constructor of MyClass is protected (or public if required). Question modified

Comment: Moreover, you'll have to create an instance in some initialization phase whereas in standard singleton, you usually have lazy initialization.